# Que significa esto y como corregirlo?

Tags: php, mssql

Hola tengo este script me imagino suma los resultados pero no termino de entender como funciona pues me da un error el cual desconozco:

```
$execSql=mssql_query($sql);
$results=mssql_fetch_array($execSql);
for($i=0;$i<mssql_num_fields($execSql);$i++){
    $fieldName  =mssql_field_name($execSql,($i+1));
```

el error es el siguiente:

```
[07-Apr-2020 18:48:08 America/Caracas] PHP Warning:  mssql_field_name(): Bad column offset in /home/createso/shaiyamorker.createsoftw.com/includes_shaiya/player/function-player_online.php on line 61
```

Comment: El uso de [`mssql_num_fields`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-num-fields.php) (que por cierto es una función **obsoleta** hace ya varios años), hace pensar que lo que pretende este script es mostrar los campos de ese resultado. OJO, lo que trae esa función es el nombre de las columnas de la tabla. Sería útil por ejemplo si quieres usarlos en el `thead` de una tabla HTML. La primera asignación que hay dentro del bucle no tiene demasiado sentido, a no ser que uses `$fieldName` inmediatamente después para algo, porque al estar en el bucle, `$fieldName` se va a sobre-escribir... [+]

Comment: [+] ... en cada iteracción. En cualquier caso, si nos dices lo que quieres hacer, quizá podremos ayudarte mejor. Tu código parece antiguo (todas las funciones que usas son obsoletas) y no entiendo muy bien qué uso quieres darle aquí a `mssql_num_fields`. Sería bueno que lo expliques para arrojar un poco de luz en el asunto.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no conozco mucho de php pero si el primer campo del resultado de la consulta es el numero 0, en la linea

```
$fieldName  =mssql_field_name($execSql,($i+1));
```

debería quedar

```
$fieldName  =mssql_field_name($execSql,($i));
```